# How do I set the width of a HTML element with a Django variable?

Tags: python, html, css, django, width

Right now, I have a dictionary, where I have each element and the width of it stored. I'm passing that with Django to an HTML template, where I'm rendering each of the dict objects with a for loop. However, I need to be able to set the width of a 'div' using what is in the Django template. So basically, if I have "100%" in the dict, then I want the corresponding div to also have a width of 100%. The code I tried is below, but it isn't working, and in the console, it says "invalid property value".

**Python code:**

```
objects={"key": "100%", "key2": "90%"}
return render(request, "website/updates.html", {
    "objects": objects
})
```

**website/updates.html**

```
{% for item, width in objects.items %}
      <div style="width: {{width}}">
           Other irrelevant code here
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not totally sure here, but you shouldn't name your variables "dict", as that's a reserved keyword in python. Try changing the name and see if you get the same error?

Comment: @csinchok I tried that, it still isn't setting the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: `<div style="background-color: black; width: {{ dict.key }}">`

This way you don't have to loop over the dictionary object.

Comment: I'm looping over the dict because I need to create an HTML element for every object in the dict, and each of them needs to have a different width. Is there any way to set the styling with this?

Comment: Maybe you should post the error message you're getting because I got it to work on my end.

Comment: Ah wait I figured out the problem, it was just a typo smh :(

Comment: Thank you though!